# Hide soft keyboard when an EditText field receives focus

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-hardware-keyboard

I am currently developing an enterprise Android application,
which is deployed on devices that have a hardware keyboard.
Most of the EditText fields require numerical input, so naturally
it is much more convenient and faster to enter the data via the 
hardware keyboard.
The problem is the soft keyboard pops up automatically when an EditText field receives focus and 
sometimes obscures the currently focused field and other parts of the screen.

My question is how can i prevent the poping up of the soft keyboard
when an EditText field receives focus.

And the second question is how can i still show the soft keyboard on 
some other event, for example on long click on an EditText field.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: No, that question is about just hiding the keyboard, and he is able to show when you press a editText again. Here the question is about hiding the keyboard to not show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding soft keyboard forever:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

To show after hiding "forever":

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0);
```